# HTML AUTOCOMPLETEFOR as required field

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following line of code and I need that field to be mandatory, I already put the "Required", but when running the code, it does not make the field mandatory and simply allows that field to be empty,

```
@Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.AgenteNaviero_Codigo, model => model.AgenteNaviero_Nombre, false, Url.Action("AutocompleteAgenteNavieroSearch", "AgenteNaviero", new { area = "Maestros", required = "required" }), "width: 80%")
```

I appreciate you can help me or say how I can make you take that field as mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to apply DataAnnotation on your model? I think you could do something like this to your model properties

```
[Required]
AgenteNaviero_Codigo
```

And then in your action,

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteAgenteNavieroSearch(YourModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ...
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

For example,

```
 public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre must be specified")]
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between $1 and $100")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        public string Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(movie);
}
```

For more details, you can take a look from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model)